# How do I generate multiple news XML sitemaps using sys_category

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-news, typo3-10.x, xml-sitemap

**Version:**

> TYPO3 10.4.18, News 8.5.2

**Problem:**

I need to generate multiple XML sitemaps, where all news originate from a *single* folder ID. They need to link to *different* news detail pages, based on *different* categories.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/8.0/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Seo/Index.html) I need to use the extended sitemap `GeorgRinger\News\Seo\NewsXmlSitemapDataProvider`, it also states the following:

> Single-view page for news from this category of a sys_category you need to use a custom provider.

It also states:

> To enable the category detail page handling, checkout the setting `useCategorySinglePid = 1` in the following full example:

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    config {
        xmlSitemap {
            sitemaps {
                news {
                    provider = GeorgRinger\News\Seo\NewsXmlSitemapDataProvider
                    config {
                        excludedTypes = 1,2
                        additionalWhere =
                        ## enable these two lines to generate a Google News sitemap
                        # template = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/News/GoogleNews.xml
                        # googleNews = 1

                        sortField = datetime
                        lastModifiedField = tstamp
                        pid = 84
                        recursive = 2
                        url {
                            pageId = 116
                            useCategorySinglePid = 1

                            hrDate = 0
                            hrDate {
                                day = j
                                month = n
                                year = Y
                            }

                            fieldToParameterMap {
                                uid = tx_news_pi1[news]
                            }

                            additionalGetParameters {
                                tx_news_pi1.controller = News
                                tx_news_pi1.action = detail
                            }

                            useCacheHash = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above I can see that in `pid` Newsitems are stored, `pageId` is where the detail page is. `useCategorySinglePid` enables the category detail page handling. So how and where do I define what specific category should be shown in the sitemap? Do I have to define this using `additionalWhere`? The way the documentation tries to explain what needs to be done is rather confusing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I tried to find a solution but with no success.

At the end I have something like this:

```
additionalWhere = uid IN (SELECT uid_foreign FROM sys_category_record_mm WHERE uid_local=14)
```

Where `uid_local` is `uid` of category. Resolved with help from Kurt, thank you.

```
plugin.tx_seo.config {
xmlSitemap {
    sitemaps {
        innovationen {
            provider = GeorgRinger\News\Seo\NewsXmlSitemapDataProvider
            config {
                additionalWhere = uid IN (SELECT uid_foreign FROM sys_category_record_mm WHERE uid_local=11)
                sortField = sorting
                lastModifiedField = tstamp

                pid = 156

                recursive = 2
                url {
                    pageId = 157
                    useCategorySinglePid = 1

                    fieldToParameterMap {
                        uid = tx_news_pi1[news]
                    }
                    additionalGetParameters {
                        tx_news_pi1.controller = News
                        tx_news_pi1.action = detail
                    }
                    useCacheHash = 0
                }
            }
        }
        trends {
            provider = GeorgRinger\News\Seo\NewsXmlSitemapDataProvider
            config {
                additionalWhere = uid IN (SELECT uid_foreign FROM sys_category_record_mm WHERE uid_local=12)
                sortField = sorting
                lastModifiedField = tstamp

                pid = 156

                recursive = 2
                url {
                    pageId = 160
                    useCategorySinglePid = 1

                    fieldToParameterMap {
                        uid = tx_news_pi1[news]
                    }
                    additionalGetParameters {
                        tx_news_pi1.controller = News
                        tx_news_pi1.action = detail
                    }
                    useCacheHash = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```